# WordPress - how to get posts content and title

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to WordPress and I need to retrieve the content and title of all the posts but can't find my way. here is my code.

```
require_once("blog/wp-load.php");

$the_query = new WP_Query( ['posts_per_page' = -1]);

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();

        $a= $the_query->post_content;
        echo $a;

    }

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

It is giving me a blank page

Answer (score 0):

Once the loop has the posts in storage you can use other methods to get information about the posts.

Example for a card holding an image, title of a piece of content, etc.

```
<section>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="card">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
               <a href='<?php the_permalink();?>'>
                  <div class="card-img-bottom" style=' height:100%;background-image: url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url( 'full' ); ?>);background-size:cover;'>
                  </div>
               </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
               <div class="card-block">
                  <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                  <p class="card-text"><?php  the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Each post being returned by the loop would then be embedded in that context (HTML/CSS)

At the bottom of your page above a footer call you can also end the loop like this:

```
 <?php endwhile; else : ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Also to specify. You can obtain the content with

```
 the_content();
```

The title with

```
the_title();
```

And the link to the post with

```
 the_permalink();
```